# Using Webmatrix helpers in regular ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, webmatrix

The [Webmatrix Html helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/erikreitan/webmatrix-helpers) look quite handy. Is there any way to use them from a regular ASP.NET MVC project with Visual Studio?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [really easy](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=594).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look here:

http://blog.stevelydford.com/2011/02/fun-with-webmatrix-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-3/